# How to assign the result of echo to a variable in bash script

Tags: linux, bash

I'm a Linux newbie and have copied a bash script that extracts values from a XML.
I can echo the result of a calculation perfectly, but assigning this to a variable doesn't seem to work.

```
#!/bin/bash
IFS=$'\r\n' result=(`curl -s "http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/smartmeter/modules" | \
xmlstarlet sel -I -t -m "/modules/module" \
    -v "cumulative_logs/cumulative_log/period/measurement" -n \
    -v "point_logs/point_log/period/measurement" -n | \
sed '/^$/d' `)

# uncomment for debug
echo "${result[0]}"*1000 |bc 
gas=$(echo"${result[0]}"*1000 |bc)

echo "${result[0]}"*1000 |bc
```

Gives me the result I need, but I do not know how to assign it to a variable.

I tried with tick marks:

```
gas=\`echo"${result[0]}"*1000 |bc\`
```

And with `$(`

Can somebody point me in the right direction?

Comment: You put no space between `echo` and `"${result....`.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

If you want to use `bc` anyway then
you can just use back ticks , why you are using the backslashes? this code works , I just tested.

```
  gas=`echo ${result[0]}*1000 | bc`
```

Use one space after `echo` and no space around * operator

Comment: `$( ...)` and backticks are both forms of command-substitution. Backticks are only for systems that don't have `$(..cmd..)`. Join the 1990's and start using the "new" form of command-substitution! ;-) Good luck to all.

Comment: You are welcome , you can execute any command like that within backtiks and assign the result to a variable

Answer (score 9):

There is no need to use `bc` nor `echo`. Simply use the [arithmetic expansion `$(( expression ))`](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Arithmetic-Expansion) for such operations:

```
gas=$(( ${result[0]} * 1000))
```

This *allows the evaluation of an arithmetic expression and the substitution of the result*.

Comment: I get the error `syntax error: invalid arithmetic operator (error token is ".533 * 1000")` I read that bash script variables are problematic with float?

Comment: @Remco yes, arithmetic expansion is just on integers.

Comment: @fedorqui : FWIW, `echo $(( .533 * 1000 ))` works in ksh93+. I thought maybe it was the dbl-quotes visible in Remco's error msgs, but `".533 * 1000"` works in ksh too ;-/ ! Good luck to all.

Comment: @shellter I remember doing some investigation some time ago and yes, from `ksh93` floating-point arithmetic is available. From [Learning the korn shell](http://docstore.mik.ua/orelly/unix3/korn/ch06_02.htm), _While expr and ksh88 were limited to integer arithmetic, ksh93 supports floating-point arithmetic. As we'll see shortly, you can do just about any calculation in the Korn shell that you could do in C or most other programming languages._